# Хранение информации о сущности в нескольких языках[EF]

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Хочу добавить поддержку нескольких языков(пока en/ru) для некоторых сущностей. Сущность - таблица в EF. Одно из требований - легкое добавление информации на новом языке. Погуглил и пока единственное что нашел(на англ ветке) следующий пример.

Например, есть api с информацией о фильмах. Для данного api рассмотрим следующие таблицы:

1. Language - язык
2. Movie - общая информация о фильме, которая одинаковая для всех языков - связи, целочисленные/вещественные и прочие данные(кроме строк)
3. TranslatedMovie - переведенная информация о фильме на каждом языке(описание, слоган и.т.п)

В качестве субд использую postgresql.

```
public class Language
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Language")]
    public ICollection<TranslatedMovie> TranslatedMovies{ get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Movie
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int Budget { get; set; } //Информация одинаковая для всех языков

    public ICollection<TranslatedMovie> TranslatedMovies { get; set; }

    public Movie()
    {
        TranslatedMovies = new List<TranslatedMovie>();
    }
}
```

```
public class TranslatedMovie
{
    public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
    public Profile Profile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Language")]
    public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; } //Для каждого языка разная информация
                                            //В данном случае это описание
}
```

**Оптимальное ли это решение или есть лучше?**

Comment: Ничего не понятно... Где Вы планируете это использовать? Что такое `профиль`? Что Вы имеете ввиду под высказыванием "поддержка нескольких языков для моделей"? Когда Вы задаёте вопрос, то у Вас все особенности в голове, но у тех, кто читает вопрос, немного не так.

Comment: @XelaNimed отредактировал вопрос

Comment: А не проще использовать отдельную таблицу для каждого языка? Или одну с разными столбцами для каждого языка? Не сохранять конкретно в сущностях, а просто ссылаться на id строки и необходимый язык?

Comment: @XelaNimed отдельные таблицы слишком накладно использовать. Если переводимых таблиц 15 изначально, то для 2 языков это уже 30таблиц. А если таблиц 50 и языков 10, то уже 500 таблиц. Сомневаюсь, что в крупных компаниях только на перевод тратят 500 таблиц. А использование одной таблицы с кучей полей - нарушение НФ.

Comment: А как в Вашем варианте будет происходит смена языка? А добавление нового? Перевод? Как [пример](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/database-stored-messages-for-i18n-in-spring-boot/).

Comment: Смены языка не происходит. При запросе к api просто добавляется необязательный параметр language=ru или en(по умолчанию). Добавление нового: если это таблицы-справочники(список стран и другая статичная информация, то ее добавляю уже заранее), иначе пользователь ее добавляет сам при post запросе(по желанию тоже). Ваш пример по ссылке посмотрел. Там одна таблица - языки с одним переводимым свойством locale. У меня чуть-чуть сложнее, т.к свойств может быть гораздо больше.